# Enforce https when using tlmgr to install packages

Tags: tlmgr

Is there a way to enforce https when using tlmgr to install packages?

Comment: The OP did not say why, but I know some firewalls block FTP.

Comment: Why? Do you mean something beyond use of `tlmgr option repository` which would seem to address @RobtAll's conjectured motivation? Or do you mean HTTPS as opposed to HTTP? But I can't imagine the point of that .....

Comment: Why does anyone use https instead of http?